# Modx - регистрация и смена пароля через пакет Login сразу в двух БД

Tags: php, modx

Только начал пользоваться Modx.  
Настроил регистрацию и авторизацию пользователей через пакет Login по инструкции https://itchief.ru/modx/login-registration 
На сайте регистрация проходит успешно. Но мне нужно по мимо регистрации на самом сайте, еще и в другую БД (игровую).

Сейчас это все выглядит слишком сложно:

1. Пользователь регистрирует аккаунт на сайте;
2. Заходит в ЛК;
3. в ЛК переходит в по ссылке на регистрацию игрового аккаунта.

Регистрация игрового аккаунта реализована при помощи отдельного сниппета:

```
<?php
//Подключение к игровой БД 
if(!@mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','user','pswd') || !@mysql_select_db('db_name')) 
    echo "<div class='callout callout-danger'>
                <h4>Сторонние силы вмешались в процесс!</h4>
          </div>"; 
else {
$trules = 
'<form name="reg_rules" method="post" action=""> 
            <div class="callout callout-info">
                <h4><i class="icon fa fa-info"></i> Прочти перед регистрацией!</h4>

                <p>Текст</p>
            </div>
                
            <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2"> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="rules"> Согласен<br>
            <center><input type="submit" value="Далее" class="btn btn-block btn-success"> </center>
</form>'; 
$tform = 
'<form name="reg_form" method="post" action="">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input placeholder="Логин" name="login" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="14">  
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" class="form-control"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input name="pass" placeholder="Пароль" type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="16"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input name="repass" placeholder="Повтор пароля" type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="16"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      
              
        <input type="hidden" name="step" value="3">
        <center><input type="submit" value="Создать" class="btn btn-block btn-success"></center>
</form>'; 

$step = $_POST['step']; 

if (isset($_POST['step'])){ 
switch ($step){ 
case '2':{ 
$rules = $_POST['rules']; 
if ($rules == "on") 
//На шаге 2 выводится форма, если пользователь согласен с правилами 
$centertext = $tform; 
else 
//Если не согласен 
$centertext = '
<div class="callout callout-warning">
                <h4>Что-то не так!</h4>

                <p>Регистрация невозможна без согласия с правилами сервера!</p>
              </div>
<center><input type="button" onclick="history.back(-2); return false;" value="Назад" class="btn btn-block btn-success"></center>
'; 
break; 
} 
case '3':{ 
if ((isset($_POST['login']))AND(isset($_POST['pass']))AND(isset($_POST['repass']))AND(isset($_POST['email']))){ 
$login = $_POST['login']; 
$pass = $_POST['pass']; 
$repass = $_POST['repass']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

if(strlen($login) < 6 or strlen($login) > 16) 
$err[] = '<div class="callout callout-warning"><p>Минимальная длинна логина - 6 символов. Максимальная длина логина - 16 символов</p></div>'; 
if(strlen($pass) < 8 or strlen($pass) > 16) 
$err[] = '<div class="callout callout-warning"><p>Минимальная длинна пароля - 8 символов. Максимальная длина пароля - 16 символов</p></div>'; 
if($pass==$login) 
$err[] = '<div class="callout callout-warning"><p>Не разрешено использовать одинаковые логин и пароль</p></div>'; 
if($pass!=$repass) 
$err[] = '<div class="callout callout-warning"><p>Введенные пароли не совпадают</p></div>'; 
if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,}$/",$login)) 
$err[] = '<div class="callout callout-warning"><p>Логин содержит запрещенные символы.</p></div>'; 
if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,}$/",$pass)) 
$err[] = '<div class="callout callout-warning"><p>Пароль содержит запрещенные символы.</p></div>';
if(!eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$", $email)) 
$err[] = '<div class="callout callout-warning"><p>Не правильный формат адреса электронной почты</p></div>'; 
if (preg_match('/[а-я]/i', $pass))
$err[]  = '<div class="callout callout-warning"><p>Пароль не может содержать кириллицу</p></div>';
if (preg_match('/[а-я]/i', $login))
$err[]  = '<div class="callout callout-warning"><p>Логин не может содержать кириллицу</p></div>';

if ($err!='') 
$centertext = implode('', $err); 
} 
else{ 
$centertext = '<div class="callout callout-warning"><p>Не заполнены все обязательные поля.</p></div>'; 
} 
if ($centertext ==""){ 

$db = mysql_pconnect('127.0.0.1','user','pswd'); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4'); 
mysql_select_db('db_name'); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT login FROM `accounts` WHERE login='$login'"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){ 
$gamepass = base64_encode(hash('whirlpool', $pass, true)); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts(login, password, lastactive, accessLevel, lastIP, lastServerID, l2email) VALUES('".$login."' , '".$gamepass."', '1', '0', '".$ip."', '1', '".$email."');") or die(mysql_error()); 
$centertext = "Добро пожаловать. Аккаунт $login успешно создан."; 
} 
else{ 
$centertext = "К сожалению этот логин уже занят."; 
} 
} 
break; 
} 
default:{ 
$centertext = ""; 
} 
} 
} 
if ($centertext == "") 
$centertext = $trules; 
echo $centertext;
}
```

Хотелось бы сделать единую регистрацию, чтобы при создании аккаунта на сайте, сразу же создавался и игровой аккаунт. Следовательно и при смене пароля от аккаунта, менялся и пароль от игрового аккаунта.

Но я не могу понять как и где изменить код пакета Login чтобы добавить подключение к игровой БД и данные при регистрации и смене пароля записывались в игровую БД.

Пожалуйста, помогите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте через `&postHooks` параметр: укажите название сниппета, который после регистрации в основной базе будет делать регистрацию и в кастомной. Всю логику, само собой, надо прописать в сниппете, как с ними работать можно например посмотреть здесь: https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/login/login.tutorials/using-pre-and-post-hooks#switchsettings Постхуки выполняются сразу после регистрации.Есть еще `preHooks`, они срабатывают до основной регистрации, но сразу после валидации полей, вдруг вам тоже пригодится зачем-то еще.

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось сделать регистрацию и в основную и в игровую бд. Но в игровую бд запись заносится сразу же, без подтверждения основного аккаунта.. Как-то можно сделать чтобы только после активации основного аккаунта заносились данный в игровую БД?